# How to send an array of objects in Zapier UI builder

Tags: javascript, json, zapier

I'm trying to send an array of objects to an API endpoint using Zapier and can't seem to format my data correctly. Below is what the endpoint is expecting

```
[{
        "date": "2014-02-13",
        "do": "DO140213001",
        "address": "63 Ubi Avenue 1 Singapore 408937"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-02-13",
        "do": "DO140213002",
        "address": "59 Ubi Avenue 1 Singapore 408938",
        "delivery_time": "02:00 PM - 05:30 PM"
    }
]
```

This is waht i have in the Zapier UI web builder

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://app.detrack.com/api/v1/deliveries/update.json',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': bundle.authData.api_key
  },
  params: {

  },
  body:  [{
  }]
};
return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
  });
```

Comment: Does it work if there is only one object without array?

Comment: @MuraliNepalli yes it does in Paw a API tester but can't get it to work in Zapier

Comment: I think 'body's value should be an object, not an array. so i suggest you try with the following first    body:  {   "date": "2014-02-13",
        "do": "DO140213001",
        "address": "63 Ubi Avenue 1 Singapore 408937"
  }

Comment: @MuraliNepalli yes that works. but how can I send multiple objects with the same key but different values?

Comment: can you try with  body: {  {
        "date": "2014-02-13",
        "do": "DO140213001",
        "address": "63 Ubi Avenue 1 Singapore 408937"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-02-13",
        "do": "DO140213002",
        "address": "59 Ubi Avenue 1 Singapore 408938",
        "delivery_time": "02:00 PM - 05:30 PM"
    } }

Comment: Got it. you need to send this way     -- data: JSON.stringify( [ { "date": "2014-02-13", "do": "DO140213001", "address": "63 Ubi Avenue 1 Singapore 408937" }, { "date": "2014-02-13", "do": "DO140213002", "address": "59 Ubi Avenue 1 Singapore 408938", "delivery_time": "02:00 PM - 05:30 PM" } ] );

Comment: @MuraliNepalli but I need to send multiple pieces of data through Zapier and the only way to get an array that I have found is by using their line item feature but it requires a group key for example `"data": [{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }]`  and that's the main issue is I don't need a group key.

Comment: @luke how did you solve this? I have the same problem that I want to return an array so that users can later add several rows in a GoogleSheet. Andd tip?

Comment: @Mattk90 if your using the visual builder check out these docks https://platform.zapier.com/docs/input-designer#how-to-add-a-line-item-group